# Show $\nabla^2g=-f$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-writing, poissons-equation

Let a continuous function $f(x,y,z)$ have first order partial derivatives $f_x,f_y,f_z$ exist at every point and the function and all its first order partial derivatives are absolutely integrable.
If for $x',y',z' \in R$ there is a non negative integrable function $h(x',y',z')$ such that for some measurable set $A \subset R^3$ with finite Lebesegue outer measure:

$|f_x(x+x',y',z')|< h(x',y',z')$ almost everywhere in $A$ for some $m-\epsilon<x<m+\epsilon$

$|f_y(x',y+y',z')|< h(x',y',z')$ almost everywhere in $A$  for some $m-\epsilon<y<m+\epsilon$

$|f_z(x',y',z+z') |< h(x',y',z')$ almost everywhere in $A$ for some $m-\epsilon<z<m+\epsilon$

$ r'=\sqrt{|x-x'|^2+|y-y'|^2+|z-z'|^2}$

let:
$$g(x,y,z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {f(x',y',z')}{4\pi r'}dx'dy'dz',\ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \nabla^2g= \frac {\partial^2g}{\partial x^2}+\frac {\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}+\frac {\partial^2g}{\partial z^2}$$

How to show that $\nabla^2g=-f$  ?

Comment: It would be much easier to work with the representation of the Laplacian in spherical coordinates.

Comment: yes you can convert to spherical coordinates. but the difficulty remains.

Comment: Note that the integral is $N \ast f$, where $N$ is the Newton potential (or its negative, can't remember the conventions), satisfying $\Delta N = -\delta$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution. So $\Delta g = -f$ holds in the sense of distributions.  I'm not convinced that $\Delta g$ needs to exist anywhere in the classical sense if only $f \in L^1$ is assumed.

Comment: What do you mean by $\nabla^2 g = f$ a.e.? Who says that derivatives of $g$ exist in the usual sense? The equation only has meaning in the sense of distributions.

Comment: I made some progress by showing $g$ is of bounded variation and therefore its first partial derivatives all exist a.e . I was able to the same for $\nabla^2$ . now I just need to show $\nabla^2$ =$-f$ a.e

Comment: @Hans Engler. Interestingly the partial derivatives exist a.e and the same for $\nabla^2$. It is not difficult to show that.

Comment: Note that $L^1$ maximal regularity does not hold for the Laplacian. Concretely in this case, if $f \in L^1$, it does not follow that the second order partial derivatives of $g$ are all in $L^1$. This is different from the $L^p$ case, for $1 < p < \infty$.

Comment: Yes but $ \nabla^2g $ can still be in $ L^1 $ even if non of the $ \frac {\partial^2g}{\partial x^2} $ is in $L^1$

Comment: @HansEngler  I found easier condition , I could throw away absolute continuity jargons since the partial derivatives are absolutely integrable. To my surprise the measure theoretic version of  Leibniz integral rule can be used and makes my proof shorter and more elegant. I will post my shorter proof very soon. It is amazing the solution of this problem has only be treated in the context of distributions in most Maths and Physics textbooks despite the existence of classical solution. I look forward to submitting my shorter proof for publication in some journal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theorem 1.** If a sequence of  absolutely continuous functions {$f_n$} converges pointwise to some $f$  and if the sequence of  derivatives {$f_n’$}  converges almost everywhere to some  $g$ and if {$f_n’$} is uniformly integrable then $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty} f_n’ = g= f’$ almost everywhere. Where the derivative of  $f$ is $f’$. If the convergence is pointwise and $ g $ is continuous then $ f'$ = $ g $ everywhere.

Proof : by FTC  $f_n(x) – f_n(a) = \int_a^x f_n’ dx$

By Vitali convergence theorem : $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}\int_a^x f_n’ dx = \int_a^x g dx$

Therefore $\lim\limits_{n\mapsto \infty}( f_n(x) – f_n(a))= \int_a^x g dx$

$f(x)-f(a) = \int_a^x g dx$

$f(x)’=g$ almost everywhere

If the convergence is pointwise and $ g $ is continuous then $ f'$ = $ g $ everywhere.

**Theorem 2.** **Divergence Theorem**

**Theorem 3.** **Leibniz Integral Rule : Measure theoretic version**

$ r'=\sqrt{|x-x'|^2+|y-y'|^2+|z-z'|^2}$

$ r=\sqrt{|x'|^2+|y'|^2+|z'|^2}$

Define $f_N=\int_{-N}^{N} \int_{-N}^{N} \int_{-N}^{N}f(x’,y’,z’)\frac {1}{4\pi r’}erf(\frac {r’N}{\sqrt 2})dx'dy'dz'$

$erf(\frac {r’N}{\sqrt 2})=\frac {2}{\sqrt \pi}\int_0^{\frac {r’N}{\sqrt 2}}e^{-t^2}dt$

$\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty}erf(\frac {r’N}{\sqrt 2})=1$

$\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} f_{N} = g$

$\frac {1}{4\pi r’}erf(\frac {r’N}{\sqrt 2})$ can be developed into a power series of $r'$ by simply plugging Taylor's expansion of $erf(\frac {r’N}{\sqrt 2})$

By theorem 3 $\frac {\partial f_{N}}{\partial x}=\int_{-N}^{N} \int_{-N}^{N} \int_{-N}^{N} \frac {f(x',y',z')(x'-x)erf(\frac {r’ N}{\sqrt 2})}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'-$
$\int_{-N}^{N} \int_{-N}^{N} \int_{-N}^{N}\frac {N(x' - x)f(x',y',z') e^{-(\frac {r’^2 N^2}{ 2})}}{2\pi\sqrt{2\pi} r'^2}dx'dy'dz'$

The existence of$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {f(x',y',z')}{4\pi r'}dx'dy'dz' $ and  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {f(x',y',z')(x'-x)}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz' $ which is also continuous can be shown by converting to polar coordinates.

Now we can apply theorem $1$  to conclude  $\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} \nabla f_{N} =\nabla g$

$\nabla^2 f_{N} =-\int_{-N}^N \int_{-N}^N \int_{-N}^N \frac {N^3f(x',y',z')e^{-(\frac {r’^2 N^2}{ 2})}}{(\sqrt{2\pi})^3}dx'dy'dz'$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {f(x',y',z')(x'-x)}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz' = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {f(x'+x,y'+y,z'+z)(x')}{4\pi r^3}dx'dy'dz'$

it follows from theorem 3 :
$\nabla^2  g=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {f_x(x'+x,y'+y,z'+z)(x')}{4\pi r^3}dx'dy'dz'+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {f_y(x'+x,y'+y,z'+z)(y')}{4\pi r^3}dx'dy'dz'+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {f_z(x'+x,y'+y,z'+z)(z')}{4\pi r^3}dx'dy'dz'$

Now application of  dominated convergence theorem ,the fact that $\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} \nabla f_{N} =\nabla f$ and using theorem 2 : $\int_a^b \int_a^b \int_a^b(\nabla .\nabla  f_N )dxdydz = \int_{R^2} \nabla f_N .dA$

$ \int_{R^2} \nabla g .dA=\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty}\int_{R^2} \nabla f_{N} .dA$

$\int_a^b  \int_a^b \int_a^b \lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} (\nabla^2  f_{N} )=\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} \int_a^b  \int_a^b \int_a^b  (\nabla^2  f_{N} )$

And $\int_a^b \int_a^b \int_a^b(\nabla^2  g )dxdydz =\int_{R^2} \nabla g .dA=\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty}\int_{R^2} \nabla f_{N} .dA=\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} \int_a^b  \int_a^b \int_a^b  (\nabla^2  f_{N} )=\int_a^b  \int_a^b \int_a^b \lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} (\nabla^2  f_{N} )$

$\int_a^b \int_a^b \int_a^b((\nabla^2  g )-\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} (\nabla^2  f_{N} ))dxdydz=0$

Since this is true for any $a$ and $b$ ,we conclude $\nabla^2g=\lim\limits_{N\mapsto \infty} (\nabla^2  f_{N} )=-f$ .

Comment: Sadly i had to  edit the previous question . I had to assume $f$ is bounded and Riemann integrable .

Comment: The definition of absolute continuity for a function $f(x,y,z)$  of several variables  may look awkward.It may look like most functions won't fit the definition. However any continuous function that has first partial derivatives that are finite except on a countable set and the the partial derivatives are integrable. Then it satisfies our definition of absolute continuity.

Comment: Do note that many users find numerous and frequent edits "less than ideal" -- see [this Meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-much-self-editing-is-too-much) for instance. It seems like there should be some way to improve the post, but without multiple edits in short timespans (honestly, with a limited amount of editing, in general).

Comment: 58th edit: "added 1 character in body". Really?

Comment: I stumbled upon the identity:$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac {\partial f(x',y',z')}{\partial x'}\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac {\partial f(x',y',z')}{\partial y'}\frac {y'-y}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'+$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac {\partial f(x',y',z')}{\partial z'}\frac {z'-z}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'=-f(x,y,z)$

Comment: Infact the identity is equivalent to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \nabla .( f\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3}+f\frac {y'-y}{4\pi r'^3}+f\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3})dx'dy'dz'$ because $\nabla .(\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3}+\frac {y'-y}{4\pi r'^3}+\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3})=0$

Comment: Do you think there is an easier solution, if you relax some of the conditions? I mean this problem should have been addressed long before Lebesgue integration (1902).

Comment: @lalala you are right I found easier condition , I could throw away absolute continuity jargons since the partial derivatives are absolutely integrable. To my surprise Leibniz integral rule can be used and makes my proof shorter and more elegant. I will post my shorter proof very soon. It is amazing the solution of this problem has only be treated in the context of distributions in most Maths and Physics textbooks despite the existence of classical solution. I look forward to submitting my shorter proof for publication in some journal.