# Regarding absolute continuity of some function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, functions

$f (y) $ is continuous function of y.

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(y)||(x-y)|^2dy$ is finite for all x

Given $h(x)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)(x-y)^2dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y+x)(y)^2dy$

is $h(x)$ always absolutely continuous?

If no. What conditions on $f(y)$ makes $h(x)$ absolutely continuous?

Comment: i couldn't construct a counter example

Comment: why do you say is finite if you take $f(y)=c$ then you are basically integrating $y^2$ over $\mathbb R$ which is not finite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write
$$
        \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)(x-y)^2dy=x^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)dy-2x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)ydy+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)y^2dy.
$$
Because of your condition, its not difficult to show that the integrals on the right are absolutely convergent.

Comment: Please could you show $\sum_k |x_{k+1}-x_k| \le \epsilon$ implies $\sum_k |h(x_{k+1})-h(x_k)| \le \delta$      ?

Comment: I'll bet that you can show how that works for the second order polynomial $h(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$. That's what you have, with constants $A,B,C$.

Comment: ok thanks. the last integral contains $y^2$ i think

Comment: @stalker2133 : Thanks, I fixed that. Any continuously differentiable function is absolutely continuous.

Comment: @TrialAndErrror. thanks for the answer. I was wondering if you looked at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782377/show-nabla2g-f-almost-everywhere

Comment: It is not always easy to show absolute continuity of some functions

Comment: @stalker2133 : What you do you mean by absolutely continuous for a function of 3 variables? I'm curious about that.

Comment: I gave a definition in the appendix

Comment: For example $f= xy$ is absolutely continuous over a bounded box but not over unbounded box.

Comment: @stalker2133 : What is the definition of absolutely continuous for a function of more than 1 variable?

Comment: $f(x,y,z)$ is absolutely continuous if :$\sum_{k} |x_{k+1} - x_k|<\epsilon$ implies $\sum_{k} |f(x_{k+1},y,z) - f(x_k,y,z)|<\delta$ for every $y,z$ 
,
$\sum_{k} |y_{k+1} - y_k|<\epsilon$ implies $\sum_{k} |f(x,y_{k+1},z) - f(x,y_k,z)|<\delta$ for every $x,z$,

$\sum_{k} |z_{k+1} - z_k|<\epsilon$ implies $\sum_{k} |f(x,y,z_{k+1}) - f(x,y,z_k)|<\delta$ for every $x,y$

Comment: @stalker2133 : Separately absolutely continuous in each variable doesn't seem like a very general condition, and it's coordinate dependent. Is the function assumed to be jointly continuous? I've never seen a definition like this, and it does not seem very useful, being so coordinate dependent.

Comment: Yes $f(x,y,z)$ is jointly continuous.

Comment: actually in 3 dimensions it is very useful. I checked it. This is because the Jacobian has some nice properties

Comment: @stalker2133 : Such a function is not necessarily differentiable as a function of 3 variables. You have derivatives in each directly, but only almost everywhere in one direction. Jacobian doesn't have a lot of meaning under circumstances where the function is not differentiable, which is not implied by your condition.

Comment: I was refering to jacobian when doing volume integral and has nothing to do with $f$

Comment: Infact I was able to prove if the partial derivatives of $ f $ exist except on a countable set or if $|f(x_{k+1},y,z)-f(x_k,y,z)| \le A|x_{k+1}-x_k|$. the definition equally works for $f(r,\theta , \varphi )$. infact must continuous functions that do not satisfy any of the above 2 conditions are considered pathological in analysis.

Comment: @stalker2133 : Are you suggesting that absolutely continuity along coordinate lines in one coordinate system is going to imply it along coordinate lines in another?

Comment: No. Only under some conditions.

Comment: I was referring to cartesian to polar coordinates conversion. $f(x,y,z)$ to $f(r, \theta , \varphi )$

Comment: I found easier condition , I could throw away absolute continuity jargons since the partial derivatives are absolutely integrable. To my surprise the measure theoretic version of  Leibniz integral rule can be used and makes my proof shorter and more elegant. I will post my shorter proof very soon. It is amazing the solution of this problem has only be treated in the context of distributions in most Maths and Physics textbooks despite the existence of classical solution. I look forward to submitting my shorter proof for publication in some journal