# An identity related to Poisson's equation in 3D

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

$r'=\sqrt {(x'-x)^2+(y'-y)^2+(z'-z)^2}$

$\nabla = \frac {\partial}{\partial x'}+\frac {\partial}{\partial y'}+\frac {\partial}{\partial z'}$

I was studying Poisson's equation in 3D  [see this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1782377/show-nabla2g-f-almost-everywhere/1782758#1782758) and I stumbled upon the following identity:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac {\partial f(x',y',z')}{\partial x'}\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac {\partial f(x',y',z')}{\partial y'}\frac {y'-y}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'+$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac {\partial f(x',y',z')}{\partial z'}\frac {z'-z}{4\pi r'^3}dx'dy'dz'=-f(x,y,z)$ $\quad$ if $f(x,y,z)$ satisfies the conditions stated in the link.

Infact the identity is equivalent to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \nabla .( f\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3}+f\frac {y'-y}{4\pi r'^3}+f\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3})dx'dy'dz'=-f(x,y,z)$ because $\nabla .(\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3}+\frac {y'-y}{4\pi r'^3}+\frac {x'-x}{4\pi r'^3})=0$

It is not difficult to show that if $f(x',y'z')=f(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2)$, and the integral above exist, then the identity is true. I did this by simply converting the divergence to polar coordinates and did the integration in polar coordinates.Ofcourse It has  already been shown in the link $f(x'^2+y'^2+z'^2,\theta, \varphi)$ can still depend on $\theta$, $\varphi$ and the identity is still valid under the stated conditions. The conditions stated in the link are too restrictive I think.

My question is under which conditions is the identity always true?

Comment: I think your expression boils down to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f \Delta G d\mathbf{x}$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian and $G$ is (proportional to) the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation. Per distribution theory considerations, this would mean that your result would hold in the weak sense provided that $f$ is just continuous and would hold in the strong sense provided $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: @Ian.Thanks for your comments. did you mean it holds in the strong case if  partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous?

Comment: These are equivalent, yes.

Comment: ok, it is a special case for the conditions stated in the link.